# Linux or Android tablet with long battery life and cheap

Tags: linux, android, tablet, battery-life, cheap

I am looking for a tablet, which I will use only for email and, possibly, browsing (reading news items only). No games, videos, music, etc.

Bluettoth is not required; I am undecided about a SIM card.

I would prefer Linux, but could live with Android out of the box, especially if I could install Linux over it.

The device should be large enough to read, but should fit inside a jacket pocket, so maximum size about that of a Kindle Paperwhite.

Battery life is of great importance to me, to the extent that I would prefer a back & white, or greyscale screen, if there were such a tablet.

The cheaper, the better, but features mentioned above take precedence.

End of question, only read further if you want an explanation.

---

Background: my current 'phone suffered an accident, and I am replacing it. It is a [Ulefone Power](https://www.techradar.com/uk/reviews/ulefone-power-5s-rugged-smartphone) with a 13,000 mAH battery (yup, you read that correctly). I generally charge it every 5 or 6 days (side note, I can heartily recommend all UleFone models; this is my 5th or 6th over the years. Affordable, full featured, cheap, but realisable).

As per my question [How can I escape Google?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/187982/how-can-i-escape-google), I don't want my soul tracked by Gogole, Facetweet, etc (I don't even use them - directly -  but they are tracking me). So, I have decided to switch to a dumb 'phone.

I recall only ten years ago getting months between charges on a small, greyscale, Nokia, so will look for something similar.

I only really use a 'phone when job-hunting. Every 12 months or so, as I am freelance. A handful of people use WhatsApp, but I can retrain them to use SMS.

Beyond that, I have become accustomed to having email on the go, rather than just reading & replying when I get home of an evening. I have also taken to reading news headlines in the browser. A device that will let me do those with a modicum of privacy (let me worry about that) and a long battery life would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

1. A [Gemini](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TTT24QX) ([review](https://www.zdnet.com/article/gemini-pda-a-long-term-evaluation-of-the-reborn-psion-series-5/)) ([review](https://www.pocket-lint.com/phones/reviews/143148-planet-gemini-pda-review)) with Debian or Sailfish installed
2. a [PinePhone](https://store.pine64.org/?product=pinephone-braveheart-limited-edition-linux-smartphone-for-early-adaptor) (shipping now for *early adopters*)
3. a [PineTab](https://www.pine64.org/pinetab/) (Real Soon Now)
4. a DIY tablet based on a https://www.pine64.org/rockpro64/ with exactly the display, battery, and case you prefer (I've used cigar boxes)
5. A Pi-based [DIY handheld](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Wio-Terminal-A-Raspberry-Pi-compatible-SBC-with-an-integrated-display-Wi-Fi-and-IR.458553.0.html)
6. Installing the [/e/ OS on 89 different phones](https://e.foundation/get-support/) of your choice, or
7. a [refurb with the /e/ OS](https://e.foundation/e-pre-installed-refurbished-smartphones) overwriting all the phone-home-ware?

Comment: Great answer, thanks. D'oh! I had forgotten that I bought a Gemini when they were cheap during the funding campaign. I will dig it out & check out the battery life